# how to change schema of response data in kendo mvc

Tags: javascript, telerik, telerik-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-autocomplete

The response data form server look like this:
    `{"Data":[{"field1":25,"field2":10}]}`
but I need data source like `[{"field1":25,"field2":10}]` but I cannot change server code

So my code in kendo mvc Wrappers isn't working properly:

```
<%= Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                      .Name("search")
                      .DataTextField("field1")
                      .Filter("contains")                                                    
                      .DataSource(source => {
                          source.Read( read =>
                          {
                              read.Action("_getAjax", "Requisition").Data("onAdditionalData");

                          })
                          .ServerFiltering(true);
                      })
```

but in javascript I can use schema parameter to change response data, my code:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
            read: {
            url: "_getAjax",
            dataType: "json", 
            data: {
                text: $("#search").val()
            }
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: function (response) {
            return response.Data;
        }
    }
});
```

Does someone know how to change response data in Wrappers code like javascript code above
thanks